# Exploiting stored XSS on Android app?

Tags: xss, javascript, android

I'm testing Android app which is vulnerable to HTML injection, but I'm having problem escalating it to a stored XSS vulnerability.

I have tried these, and many more:

```
<script>alert(1)</script>
<iframe src="javascript:confirm(1)">
<a href="javascript:alert(1)">foo | linking to https://foo.com does not work also
```

None of these work - they don't render or links/tags are not clickable.
I have also tried using Android event handlers like `ontouchstart` and so on, but none of them seem to work either.

However I have noticed that I can load any image like this:

```
<img src="https://host.com/image.jpg">
```

I tried adding event handlers there too, but it did not work.

I'm out of ideas. I have tried googling for this but I can't seem to find answer why it does not work. I was thinking can it be because I'm running on Android 5.1.1, which does have some built-in XSS protection?

Comment: Maybe the server it's fetching the page from has some [csp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP) set that prevent scripts from executing ?

Comment: the render text was actually done via textview html.fromHtml which cannot execute JS as far as i know.

Answer (score 1):

After decompiling the app and going through the source code I found out that it cannot be escalated to XSS because it's using Html.fromHtml TextView